# How can I simulate UISegmentedControl with custom buttons?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm just beginning to try out development for the iPhone. My requirement is very similar to thar provided by a UISegmentedControl except I need custom buttons instead of those in a UISegmentedControl.

Here's more detail:
I need one view controller which loads the first view having 3 custom buttons on the top. Below the buttons, I need to load different views (Views?) based on which button is tapped.

Is it possible to use IB to design just the lower part of the view talked about here? I want to use as much of IB I can here.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why you can't use a UISegmentedControl here?  If you drag a UISegmented control onto a Navigation Controller in IB it will be added as a "custom" button control that looks just like a UISegmentedControl.  It's found in Apps like YouTube etc.  You can then configure it to have three sections and connect up an IBOutlet/IBAction to it easily too.

**Edit:** Also, if you use a Navigation Controller, you can very easily use IB to design your other views, as that is how Navigation Controllers work - they load their subviews typically from other nibs.  Therefore this would accomplish all you want.